# blueprintjs editable table cell tooltip or popover

Tags: blueprintjs

Similar to [How can i add add tooltips to column headers in blueprint js table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553034/how-can-i-add-add-tooltips-to-column-headers-in-blueprint-js-table)

I would like to be able to add Tooltips or Popovers to EditableCells to display validation error messages inline.

I am yet to find a workable solution.

Answer (score -1):

Gees self RTM!!! Never mind me, just noticed the tooltip property lol.